# SOLR + SSL polish characters in query

Tags: tomcat, ssl, solr

I have very strange behavior in my application when I using SSL.

My application is using SOLR for search, and

1. When I am using http (without SSL) my search results are ok in SOLR.

Example search:

```
**ProductForm:"Książka w twardej oprawie"**  - 3 results
**ProductForm:"Broszura"** - 10 results
```

Above is working ok.

2. When I am using https (SSL) my search results are NOT ok in SOLR:

   **ProductForm:"Książka w twardej oprawie"**  - 0 results (should be 3 results)
   **ProductForm:"Broszura"** - 10 results (is ok, the same results like without SSL).

Application is the same in both cases. Only difference is to use https instead of http in 2nd case.

Solr version 3.6.1

Solr is deployed on TOmcat7, application in on Jetty.

What can be the reason?

Comment: can you check if the url encoded param is UTF-8...?

Comment: in my pom.xml during build it is set to: `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`. When do you want me to check? And what is the matter if it is working over http?

Comment: When I search in Solr: **PublisherStatus:"Działalność zawieszona"** I got: **/?q=PublisherStatus%3A"Działalność+zawieszona"&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on** in URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved thanks to [solr.pl](http://solr.pl).
The problem was with Tomcat configuration.
Connector should have: **URIEncoding="UTF-8"**

Was:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="/usr/local/tomcat/ssl2/tomcat.jks"
               keyAlias="###"
               keystorePass="#########"
    />
```

is (working version):

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="/usr/local/tomcat/ssl2/tomcat.jks"
               keyAlias="###"
               keystorePass="#########"
    />
```

Comment: yes, but there are a lot of options where I can set encoding to UTF8. Your question was not clear for me and thats why I asked you where I have to check it.